# Find And Replace Text, retain Formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that I need to do a find and replace and the cells have formatting already. I need to retain the formatting. When I do an ordinary find and replace in excel, this removes the formatting. I need help to retain the formatting. I searched online and found the below link but this code is not working for me.

When I try the below code, this line is red in the code.

```
Call CharactersReplace(xRg, "<span style="background-color: #ffff00;">KK</span>", "<span style="background-color: #ffff00;">Kutools</span>", True)
```

I need help to correct this code and get this to work. Or if there is an easier way to do this, please let me know.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3760-excel-find-and-replace-preserve-formatting.html

```
Sub CharactersReplace(Rng As Range, FindText As String, ReplaceText As String, Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False)
  'UpdatebyExtendoffice20160711
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xLenFind As Long
    Dim xLenRep As Long
    Dim K As Long
    Dim xValue As String
    Dim M As Long
    Dim xCell As Range
    xLenFind = Len(FindText)
    xLenRep = Len(ReplaceText)
    If Not MatchCase Then M = 1
    For Each xCell In Rng
        If VarType(xCell) = vbString Then
            xValue = xCell.Value
            K = 0
            For I = 1 To Len(xValue)
              If StrComp(Mid$(xValue, I, xLenFind), FindText, M) = 0 Then
                xCell.Characters(I + K, xLenFind).Insert ReplaceText
                K = K + xLenRep - xLenFind
              End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub Test_CharactersReplace()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
      xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
      xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select a range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Call CharactersReplace(xRg, "<span style="background-color: #ffff00;">KK</span>", "<span style="background-color: #ffff00;">Kutools</span>", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: If I were doing this-- and assuming I were seeing the format destruction you're describing-- I might just save the file as Excel XML format, open the file in a text editor, and do a textual find/replace.  Then reopen the file in Excel and save it back to XLSX format.

Comment: I found comment added by @Marc very useful and it was suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate what I learned from the comment by @Marc but after trying to edit the xml, I found it was just too complicated. Any little mistake I made rendered the xml file unopenable by Excel.

So my solution was to copy the sheet into Word (it comes in as a Word table), using Word's Advanced Find and Replace features, and then pasting the table back into the Excel sheet. It worked for me.

Because I had lot of sheets I wanted to do this with, I made this VBA routine. After copying my data (in the first 2 columns) into Word, it removes all superscripted characters, plus does some formatting I needed. Not pretty but it worked to do 72 sheets for me, saving a lot of tedious work.

```
Sub ExcelSheetsEditedViaWord()
' note: must add a reference to the Word-library (Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Lilbrary)
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim s As String, i As Integer, sh As Worksheet, r As Range
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
  Application.StatusBar = "Opening Word  ..."
  Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  wrdApp.Visible = True
  Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
  With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .PageWidth = InchesToPoints(11)
    .PageHeight = InchesToPoints(22)
  End With
  wrdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.Percentage = 40
  i = 0
  For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set r = sh.Range("A1:B1")
    Set r = sh.Range(r, r.End(xlDown))
    r.Copy
    'wait to avoid error that sometimes stops code.
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    wrdDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    sh.Activate
    sh.Range("A1").Select
    With wrdApp.Selection
      .Find.ClearFormatting
      With .Find.Font
        .Superscript = True
        .Subscript = False
      End With
    .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
      With .Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      End With
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .WholeStory
    .Cut
    'wait some second to try to avoid error that stops code. However,
    'even when code stops, hitting debug allows it to continue
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:06"))
    sh.Paste
    With sh.Columns("A:B")
      .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
      .WrapText = True
      .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
      .Font.Size = 16
    End With
    i = i + 1
    End With
    Application.StatusBar = i & " sheets done"
  Next sh
  wrdApp.Quit False ' close the Word application
  Set wrdDoc = Nothing
  Set wrdApp = Nothing
  MsgBox i & " sheets of the workbook processed"
End Sub
```

I have some `Application.Wait()` statements where the code would fail occasionally -- something I've seen a lot with code that copy/pastes between Excel and Word. But when it fails, clicking debug and continuing works every time. As I said, not pretty but gets the job done.